# I've problem with vscode -> command 'git.viewFileHistory' not found

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-history

I want to use VSCode [git history extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory) but there's an error

> Command `git.viewFileHistory` not found

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It could be [related to this bug](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode/issues/715).

> This bug only seems to be happening for projects with multiple repos. I haven't been able to use View File History lately. I started using other functions of the extension

As it's explained in the bug report:

> I eventually figured out that I need to first use View History (git log) and choose the repo. Then, the other 2 commands work

So, try to use first `View History` and then try again with `ViewFileHistory`

There is also a [older bug report](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode/issues/238) with the same issue, where the workaround to fix it seems to be:

1. Uninstall the extension
2. remove the directory from C:\Users\ue.vscode\extensions (for windows)
3. Close VS code and reopen the vs code
4. Install extension again and we are good to go